# Show underlying div part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/3/)

I have two divs, one big and red, and one smaller, blue, part in the red one and part outside of it.

When hovered, they are shown by changing their opacity to 1. I put the red one on top and the blue one behind.

When I hover the red one it is fully displayed. When I hover the blue one, I have to hover over the part that is outside of the red one to fully display it.

What I want is, when I hover over the blue part outside the red one, to show only this part and not the part that is inside(under) the red one. How can I do this?

```js
$(".blue, .red").on({

    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.squares > div').css('opacity', '0');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    }
});
```

```css
.red {
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
     z-index:2;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
   
    top:150px;
    left:50px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="squares">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

It should look like this: http://s14.postimg.org/rqzujr9xt/Untitled.png Note that I can't split the blue part nor have a smaller one outside only. A section of the blue part MUST be under the red one. And I don't know how big it will be.

Comment: when you over the blue part, what should happen?\

Comment: Only the part that is outside the red div should be shown. Whatever is blue and over the red should remain hidden. Something like a difference between divs.

Comment: Your Red And Blue Square are positioned in the same place .
the red one has z-index bigger than the blue therefore the red one is always shown.
Try to move the blue Square to be left : 500px;
and then you will see also the blue one.

Comment: There is a small part of the blue div under the red one that is not inside the red one.

Comment: I've made them a bit smaller to avoid confusion.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc i'm not understand, if you dont want show the blue part under red part, why you put the blue part there and want it not show when hover?

Comment: why don't you change the color of the red part to white (matching with BG color) when hovered on blue div, so that only the part below it will be shown... some kind of illusion...

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc updated my post. btw instead of downvoting people you should tell them whats wrong

Comment: @AlexG I didn't downvote because I can't. I have only 1 rep.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Right, I forgot. Nvm that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSFiddle (Updated 4.0)](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/49/)**

```
<div class="js-main-container">
    <div class="js-show-content"></div>
    <div class="js-hidden-container">Content</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.js-main-container {
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
.js-show-content {
    background-color: black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;

    top:150px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity:0.1;
    z-index: 3;
}

.js-hidden-container {
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;

    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

```
var oShowContent = $(".js-show-content");
var oHiddenContainer = $(".js-hidden-container");
var oMainContainer = $(".js-main-container");

oShowContent.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        oHiddenContainer.show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        oHiddenContainer.hide();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle (Updated 3.0)](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/49/)

Comment: The problem is that you define how big the blue-inner is in height. I need to show the part without telling how big it is.

Comment: doesnt really matter. if it has content `.blue-inner` will have a height anyways. you just have to position `.blue` right.

Comment: The thing is I do not have any knowledge of .blue-inner's height value.

Comment: How about this? Now the content is always below the main-container. (previously .red) and only visible when you hover the show-content (previously .blue)

Comment: You are still defining the content's height. Don't think this method will work.

Comment: I am not. `.js-hidden-container` is the container for the hidden content

Answer (score 1):

do you want this?
https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/38/
I created an illusion by changing bg `color` of `red div` to `white` (same as bg color of `parent div`)

**UPDATE**: a small bug was fixed, now the `red div` disappears on `mouseleave`, confirm it by seeing the `border` I have added to the `red div`
https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/45/

Comment: This works only if the background is white. What if it has multiple colors, though? It will have in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: if your parent divs background is some image or multiple colors then I think you HAVE TO GO THROUGH THE ALTERNATE SOLUTION. Make the blue div fully outside of red div.

Comment: I can't make it fully outside, it will be some sort of object under it. The red div will change its size dynamically and reveal parts of the blue one. I need something like a difference between div points.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/37/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="squares">
    <div class="blue">
        <div class="upper">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="lower">&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.red {
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.1;
}
.blue {
    background-color:transparent;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;  
    top:158px;
    left:50px;
}

.blue > .upper, .blue > .lower { 
    opacity: 0.1;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.blue > .lower:hover, .red:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here you are what you asked for:

- when you HOVER RED div:  shows whole red div
- when you HOVER BLUE div: shows only the bottom (non-covered) part

Comment: But I don't want to split the blue div in two. It has to be full.

Comment: Check @Rohit Kumar solution then :)

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc in your case, the part of blue div which is inside red div is never shown. So its recommended for you to try the alternate solution I provided in my comments, i.e. make the blue div only outside of red div and not half inside and half outside

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$(".blue, .red").on({

    mouseenter: function() {

        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'red') {

            $('.squares .red').css('background-color', 'red');
            $('.squares > div').css('opacity', '0');
            $(this).css('opacity', '1');

        } else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'blue') {

            $('.squares .red').css('opacity', '1');
            $('.squares .red').css('background-color', 'white');
            $(this).css('opacity', '1');

        }


    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    }
});
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/42/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/47/)**

I just add the `z-index:-1` of `.blue` and `background-color:"white"` of `.squares`.

Comment: That works only if the background is white-only. It will not work it it has more than 1 color or if it is an image.

Answer (score -1):

You should include third block to your code. And animate it like other part. JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhspxjg0)

```js
$(".blue, .red").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.squares > div').css('opacity', '0');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    }
});

$(".blue-on-red, .red").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.squares > div').css('opacity', '0');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    }
});
```

```css
.red {
    background-color:red;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    opacity: 0;
}

.blue-on-red {
    background-color:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
    z-index: 2;
    left:100px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.blue {
    background-color:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:505px;
    z-index: 3;
    left:100px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="squares">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue-on-red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will display the whole blue div. I want to display only the small section of it that is not over the red square.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".blue, .red").on({

    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.squares > div').css('opacity', '0');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    }
});
```

```css
.red {
    background-color:red;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    
     z-index:2;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
   
    top:250px;
    left:100px;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="squares">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see here the blue part is down from the red Squere and its working when you hover this part.

Comment: that's not what he asked for

Answer (score -1):

Here's an updated fiddle of working solution as I understand your problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/0qfxw8z8/1/

Your problem was in the use of 'this' which only animated the opacity of the div that the mouse was entering. But you actually want to animate the opacity of all the divs.

**Updated JS**

```
$(".red").on({

    mouseenter: function () {
        //$('.squares > div').css('opacity', '0');
        $('.square').css('opacity', '1');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.square').css('opacity', '0');
    }
});
```

**Updated HTML**

```
 <div class="squares">
    <div class="square blue"></div>
    <div class="square red"></div>
</div>
```